# Tabular data markup should be tables or divs

Tags: html, tabular

I have a data like the image here. I need expert advice in which way I should do HTML or Divs. If I go for Div's can we achieve a effect which tables gives by default I mean if a column width increases the whole column width increases same like height wise row height increases too.

Ref Image:

[image]

Comment: Why do you ask? This sounds like a question “I know the proper markup for my data, but should I use some other markup and hope I can get close to what I need?”

Answer (score 0):

You should use tables for tabular data, this is their intended purpose.  However, this seems to be more of a gant chart, because cells seem to occasionally overlap between columns.  You could generate the chart with absolutely positioned divs, however you would need to handle all the resizing and calculations manually via javascript to have it be responsive the way you are talking about.  There is a jquery plugin that allows you to create Gant Chats found here (http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/), which seems pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

this is a job for tables! To overlap something over the edge of the column you can use position absolute to do it.